# How to call the right object classes based on variable in PHP?

Tags: php

## Situation

using PHP 5.5,

I allow my user to submit a form that has a dropdown.

Based on the dropdown, I will call different classes for a particular operation.

## What's wrong?

Currently, I use a switch case, but the number of classes will now balloon from currently 3 to 25. A switch case is ugly.

This is my code

```
    // call the right reader based on vendor
    switch($vendor) {
        case 'A':
            $vendorReader = new AReader();
            break;
        case 'B':
            $vendorReader = new BReader();
            break;
        case 'C':
        default:
            $vendorReader = new CReader();
            break;
    }
```

I deliberately named these classes this way, so it is easier to use the variable `$vendor` to call the constructor of the relevant `$vendorReader` class.

What's a good way to call the right reader class based on a variable?

Comment: why can't you use `$vendorReader = new $vendor();` ? and keep your class names as values in `$vendor`

Answer (score 1):

If the user selection is coming from a dropdown, then can I infer that it's also coming from a form via GET/POST? In that case, can you not use the name of the menu?

```
if (isset($_POST['my_class_selection_dropdown)) {
     $selection = $_POST['my_class_selection_dropdown];
     if(class_exists($selection)) {
         $vendorReader = new $selection();
     }
   }
}
```